# Data Access within SQLCLR User-Defined Aggregates (UDA)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sqlclr

I understand the limitations of SQLCLR Aggregates as it pertains to data access.  Having said that, is there a way (a workaround) to store results to a table?  It must be within SQLCLR aggregates.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish? please explain the process as this might not be what you want to do..

Comment: I appreciate everyone's responses; however, I am not asking for code/design reviews or critiques.  I just want to know is there a workaround for accessing data within the context of a User-Defined Aggregate function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to store the aggregate result into a table within the User-Defined Aggregate (UDA)? That makes little to no sense given that you can store the results into a table using plain T-SQL:

```sql
INSERT INTO SchemaName.TableName (Col1, Col2, ...)
  SELECT tab.SomeColumn, SchemaName.CustomAggregate(tab.OtherColumn)
  FROM   SchemaName.TableName tab
  GROUP BY tab.SomeColumn;
```

Essentially this works the same as if you were storing the results of any of the built-in aggregate functions, such as: `SUM`, `MIN`, `MAX`, `COUNT`, `AVG`, etc.

HOWEVER, if you *did* need to do this for some odd reason, just use an external connection (i.e. *not* `Context Connection = true;`) in the `Terminate()` method of the UDA.

Please note that a requirement of doing such data access is that the connection *not* attempt to enlist in the current transaction context (and enlisting is the default behavior). This means that your connection string will need to have the following keyword and value in it: `Enlist = false;`. And this does work as I have successfully used the following in a `Terminate()` method, and prior to adding the `Enlist=false;` I too was getting the "*Data access is not allowed in this context.  Either the context is a function or method not marked with DataAccessKind.Read or SystemDataAccessKind.Read, is a callback to obtain data from FillRow method of a Table Valued Function, or is a UDT validation method.*" error.

```cs
using (SqlConnection _Connection =
                    new SqlConnection("Trusted_Connection=true; Enlist=false;"))
{
    using (SqlCommand _Command = _Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        _Command.CommandText = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM sys.objects;";
        _Connection.Open();
        _Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Please also note that making a regular/external connection requires the Assembly to be marked as `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`. However, that does *not* require the database to be set to `TRUSTWORTHY ON`: you just sign the Assembly, create an Asymmetric Key in `master` from that DLL / Assembly, create a Login from that Asymmetric Key, and finally `GRANT` that Login the `EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY` permission.

Comment: Accessing data within a UDA is not possible.  Exception:  System.InvalidOperationException: Data access is not allowed in this context.

Comment: @T.Nguyen I updated my answer to add clarification. It does work if you add `Enlist=false;` to the ConnectionString.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the aggregate results ready in C# function, why don't you use C# ADO.NET (for database operations) to store those aggregates in database. This will be within your SQL CLR function so that you call the SQL CLR function once from database and it will store the aggregates in some table.